# How to apply custom css rule in ionic 3 through scss file

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have defined a header in ion-card. In this, I am displaying a logo. Since I had used the inline CSS so the code was working fine ut, still I thought that the styles should be maintained in a different file so I moved the style to .scss file but whats happening is the style isn't being applied to the element.

This is my login.scss code

```
page-login
        {
            ion-grid
                {
                    min-height: 100% !important;
                }
            .login-logo
                {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    display: block;
                    margin: auto;
                    height: 100px;
                    width: 100px;
                    src: url(assets/logo.png);
                }
        }
```

This is the HTML code

```
<ion-content>
        <ion-grid ion-fixed>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-12>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-card>
                        <ion-card-header>
                            <ion-img class="login-logo" alt="Text"></ion-img>
                        </ion-card-header>
                    </ion-card>
                </ion-list>
               </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
```

I don't know why the image is not being displayed.

Comment: did you check check console for error. check the location of the the image , you may have to go up directory ../../ so check console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct it as below.

**Note:** Use like this: `./assets/logo.png`

*.scss*

```
page-login
        {
            ion-grid
                {
                  min-height: 100% !important;

                .login-logo
                {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    display: block;
                    margin: auto;
                    height: 100px;
                    width: 100px;
                 }
              }

        }
```

Use `data bindings`:

*.html*

```
 <ion-img class="login-logo" alt="Text" [src]="myImage"></ion-img>
```

.ts

```
myImage:string="";

constructor(){}

this.myImage="./assets/logo.png";
```

Comment: The formatted css didnt work and where should i add the code in .ts file it says that the myImage is not detected in Login.html page

Comment: your ts code worked just update this html from `<img class="login-logo" alt="Text" [src]="myImage"></img>` to `<ion-img class="login-logo" alt="Text" [src]="myImage"></ion-img>` it need ion-image tag as it was giving error in console

Comment: Great! Done that :)